# WebAPI route - A better route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

Currently this works:

```
/api/Company/1089?children=branches
```

Controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Branch> Get(int id, string children)
```

I want my url to be this:

```
/api/Company/1089/branches
```

I can't figure out how to configure the route.

This doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(    
    name: "cb",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{children}",    
    defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Get", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, children = UrlParameter.Optional }    
);
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up for me nemesv.

Comment: Instead of adding a route to the routeConfig.cs, I needed to add it to the WebApiConfig.cs and add a MapHttpRoute.

Answer (score 0):

api/{controller}/{id}/{children}

Comment: Good catch on adding the api in front of my route.  That route (/api/Company/1089/branches) still returns a 404.

Comment: attention to the routes order and conflicts. add this rule to the top of routes. I have validated and it can work